# Array or List of objects in F#

Tags: c#, .net, f#, functional-programming

I have a custom button class derived from Button():

```
type Game15Button(position:Point) as button =
      inherit Button()
      member this.Pozition = position
```

How can I create an array of Game15Button buttons in F# as the following C# code does?

```
MyButton[] buttons = new MyButton[16]; 

int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
   for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++){     
      buttons[i] = new MyButton();
      buttons[i].Size = new Size(50, 50);
      buttons[i].Pozition = new Point(x, y);
      i++;
   }
```

Comment: Which particular part of the translation are you having a problem with?

Comment: @JohnPalmer I think i can use System.Collections.Generic in F#, thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let buttons = [
    for y in {0..3} do
    for x in {0..3} do
    yield Game15Button(Point(x, y), Size = Size(50, 50))
]
```

If you want an array, use `[| ... |]` instead.